# Getting text between strong tags with lxml and requests? Currently returning empty lists

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml, python-requests

I usually use selenium webdriver to grab content off of site, but the time it takes for the page to actually load really slows down any large scale info gathering.

I recently found requests, and have successfully used it to get an image of of a specific page. I would now like to grab some text surrounding that image.

I am able to get the html by doing

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get("website")
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
```

How would I go about sorting through this html for specific content at a specific xpath?

I've been trying to follow [this tutorial](http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/scrape/) which has me using lxml to get info from the html by using xpaths.

This seems to be working fine, but whenever I try to extract data, the lists are coming out empty.

The html looks like this:

```
<tr>
    <td class="LargeBody" align="right" width="15%" valign="top" nowrap="nowrap">
        <strong>1000</strong>  //I want this number
    </td>
    <td class="LargeBody" align="left" width="85%">
        <strong>4/0 Business Cards-Kathleen Kelly</strong>
        <font class="SmallBody">(custom)</font>
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have tried the following:

```
quantity = tree.xpath('/html/body/form[1]/table[3]/tbody[1]/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]/strong')
print quantity
[]

quantity = tree.xpath('//*[@id="jobLineItems"]/tbody[1]/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/strong')
print quantity
[]
```

I keep getting empty lists back. Any idea where I am going wrong, or how to better get the text within strong tags?

**Edit**

I used text_content() to check what content tree is looking at.

```
print tree.text_content()
```

this resulted in the log in page.

I then looked up how to pass in authentication, and edited my page request to include that.

```
page = requests.get('webpage', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

However, it was still returning an empty list.

When I try the code below, it still takes me to the log in page.

```
page = requests.get('webpage', auth=('user', 'pass'))
tree = html.fromstring(page.text)
print tree.text_content()
```

I also tried:

```
from requests.auth import HTTPDigestAuth
page = requests.get('webpage', auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

but am still landing on the log in page.

**Edit 2**

I am trying to figure out what type of authentication is using.

I tried

```
r = requests.get('website', auth=HTTPDigestAuth('user', 'pass')))
r.headers
```

which returns

```
{'content-length': '7690', 'charset': 'utf-8', 'x-powered-by': 'PHP/5.3.3', 'expires': 'Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT', 'server': 'Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)', 'connection': 'close', 'pragma': 'no-cache', 'cache-control': 'no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0', 'date': 'Tue, 14 Oct 2014 17:44:04 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/html; charset=UTF-8'}
```

But this does not seem to indicate what the authentication type is.

**Edit 3**

Someone pointed out to me elsewhere that my there is POST data being passed. [I looked up how to send POST data here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#more-complicated-post-requests). I gave the following a try.

```
payload = {'login_pass': 'pass', 'login_user': 'user'}
r = requests.post("website", data=payload)
```

This seems to take me to the page I want to be on. However, when I try

```
print r.text
```

it crashed my IDLE but data does display that shows elements from the page I am looking for rather than the log in page.

When I try

```
from lxml import html
import requests

payload = {'login_pass': '12StultsRd', 'login_user': 'megalimidi'}
r = requests.post("http://myag1.mypresswise.com/o/order.php?orderID=226523", data=payload)

print r.encoding
tree = html.fromstring(r.text)
print tree
print tree.text_content()
```

I get

```
UTF-8
<Element html at 0x112401d08>

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/meir/Documents/PYTHON/GetImageAsPdf/ImageToPDF_scrappy_beta.py", line 11, in <module>
    print tree.text_content()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/PyShell.py", line 1343, in write
    return self.shell.write(s, self.tags)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/rpc.py", line 595, in __call__
    value = self.sockio.remotecall(self.oid, self.name, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/rpc.py", line 210, in remotecall
    seq = self.asynccall(oid, methodname, args, kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/rpc.py", line 225, in asynccall
    self.putmessage((seq, request))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/idlelib/rpc.py", line 324, in putmessage
    s = pickle.dumps(message)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 70, in _reduce_ex
    raise TypeError, "can't pickle %s objects" % base.__name__
TypeError: can't pickle _ElementUnicodeResult objects
```

Comment: An easy way to debug this would be to decrease the specificity of your xpath and see if anything is returned. *E.g. try `tree.xpath('//*[@id="jobLineItems"]/tbody[1]/tr/td[2]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/table/tbody/tr/td/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]')` and walk up the path until you find something.* We can't debug this because you only provided a subset of the html.

Comment: Thank you. I just edited my post to reflect my findings. It seems I skipped the authentication step, so I keep pulling the log in page rather than the page I want. I have tried a couple of ways to authenticate, but I am still pulling the log in page unfortunately.